# two-way binding 2 child components

Tags: typescript, aurelia, two-way-binding

the following model works fine, I have a prent component (app.html + .ts) a child component (test-binding.html + .ts) and an input field with two-way binding

parent component

```
<template bindable="query">
    <require from="./test-bindable"></require>

    <input type="text" value.bind="query"/>
    <test-bindable query.bind="query"></test-bindable>

</template>
```

test-bindable.html

```
<template>
    <div>${query}</div>
</template>
```

test-bindable.ts

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class TestBindable{
@bindable query = 'potato';

valueChange(newValue, oldValue)
{
    //Do something
}
created(){
    console.log('test component created');
}
}
```

However, I am unsure how to implement the same funtionality with 2 child custom components. I can easily achieve the same using an [eventAggregator](https://aurelia.io/docs/api/event-aggregator/) and listen in my child components for the event to be fired, however, I am trying to achieve the same funcitonality using two way binding. For ex:

parent component (app.html)

```
<template bindable="query">
    <require from="./test-bindable"></require>
    <require from="./test-input"></require>

    <test-input value.bind="query"></test-bindable>
    <test-bindable query.bind="query"></test-bindable>
</template>
```

test-input.html

```
<template>
    input type="text" value.bind="test"/>
</template>
```

test-input.ts

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

    export class TestInput{
    @bindable query;

    valueChange(newValue, oldValue)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    created(){
        console.log('test component created');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to notice here, is that the default binding mode for `bindable` (using `bind`) is actually `one-way`.
if you want both of your compontent to "talk to each other" just specify `two-way` in the binding.
it sufice to bind the `test-input` with `two-way` because he is the only one who actually changes the input.

```
<template bindable="query">
    <require from="./test-bindable"></require>
    <require from="./test-input"></require>

    <test-input value.two-way="query"></test-bindable>
    <test-bindable query.bind="query"></test-bindable>
</template>
```

Comment: The default binding mode is `one-way` or `to-view` for non-form html elements and this of course includes custom components. For form fields like inputs and selects the default binding mode is `two-way`

Comment: thats why I specified  default binding mode for `bindable`

Comment: I know. I didn't mean to correct you, I just wanted to add the point of when is `.bind` two-way per default. This behavior doesn't seem to be clear to everyone.